# Sending an email to yahoo in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email

I want to send email using c#. I imlemented whole code, also use port no, host in the code. but email is not received.

**.aspx**

```
Message from: <asp:TextBox ID="text1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
Message To: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
Message subject: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="b1" runat="server" OnClick="click" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
public void click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //mail message
        MailMessage mM = new MailMessage();
        //Mail Address
        mM.From = new MailAddress( text1.Text);
        //emailid to send
        mM.To.Add(TextBox1.Text);
        //your subject line of the message
        mM.Subject = "your subject line will go here.";
        //now attached the file
        //mM.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\\attachedfile.jpg"));
        //add the body of the email
        mM.Body = "Your Body of the email.";
        mM.IsBodyHtml = false;
        //SMTP 
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
        //your credential will go here
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sender@yahoo.com", "password");
        //port number to login yahoo server
        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        //yahoo host name
        SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        SmtpServer.Send(mM);
        Label1.Text = "successfull";
        //Send the email

    }//end of try block
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }//end of catch
}//end of Yahoo Email Method
```

Comment: Recieving? You don't even know if it's sending. There's no point catching an exception you're not going to handle. It could be failing behind the scenes, and you've told your program not to tell you if that's happening by having an empty catch block.

Comment: Yes, remove the try-catch and tell us which error message you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the fault of SSL.
You have to enable SSL just like this:

```
smtpserver.EnableSsl = true;
```

Hope this helps you.